# SetConnectionString function using a Switch

Tags: c#, switch-statement, ping

Ok, my boss made this function using VB and when I converted it to C# it didn't seem to want to work just right. I get a "cannot convert type 'int' to 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus' error. And I can't seem to correct it.

```
static void SetConnectionString(string IpOrHostname)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping MyPing = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply Myreply = MyPing.Send(IpOrHostname);
            switch (Myreply.Status)
            {
                case 11010:
                    SetConnectionString("10.40.2.x");
                    break;
                //SetText("Connection timeout.")
                //SetVisible(True)
                case 11003:
                    ConnectionName = "ATRTS09AltAddress";
                    strConn = "server=10.40.2.x;User Id=blab;password=xxxx;database=xxxx";
                    strConn_del = "server=10.40.2.x;User Id=blah;password=xxx;database=xx";
                    UserConn = "server=10.40.2.x;User Id=glab;password=xxx;database=xxx";

                    break;
                case 0:
                    ConnectionName = IpOrHostname;
                    strConn = "server=" + IpOrHostname + ";User Id=blab;password=xxx;database=xx";
                    strConn_del = "server=" + IpOrHostname + ";User Id=blah;password=xxx;database=xx";
                    UserConn = "server=" + IpOrHostname + ";User Id=glab;password=xx;database=xxx";
                    break;
                default:
                    ConnectionName = "ATRTS09";
                    strConn = "server=atrts09;User Id=foox;password=xx;database=xxx";
                    strConn_del = "server=atrts09;User Id=gaaa;password=xxx;database=xx";
                    UserConn = "server=atrts09;User Id=asdfef;password=xxx;database=xxx";
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're missing a cast;

```
 switch ((int)Myreply.Status)
```

The error is being thrown because `Status` is an Enum of type `IPStatus`, perhaps VB does an implicit cast where C# requires an explicit one.

The other option would be to change the cases to use values of `IPStatus` like `case IPStatus.Success:` rather than `case 0:` or whatever int maps to success.

Answer (score 0):

`Myreply.Status` is not an integer; it is `IPStatus`.  `F12` on `IPStatus` and use the enum values instead of hardcoded integers (e.g., `IPStatus.TimedOut` instead of `11010`).